# How to create and manage icalendar VEvent in react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, icalendar, rrule

I'm developing a react native application where users can post an event specifying day, time and recurrence (weekly, daily etc...). Once these parameters have been set by the user I need to generate an ical VEvent object to send to my backend. 
The backend returns these events in VEvent objects format.
In communication with the backend, the VEvent are wrapped in a JSON.

My question is: is there a javascript library that allows me to create, decode and manage VEvents in iCalendar format?

Answer (score 0):

There are some, all you need to do is look for them on [npm.js](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=icalendar).

Unfortunately most of them have been abandoned or don't provide parsing both ways (JSON->iCal, iCal -> JSON).

Few examples:

[ics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ics), that goes from JSON -> iCal

[ical-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ical-generator), again JSON -> iCal

[ical2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ical2json), JSON -> iCal

I've been working on package of my own, to fill this void and do parsing both ways, called [ikalendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ikalendar). However I'm not trying to use this as a plug as it is still not a `1.0` version and is still in works, therefore I would not recommend it for production use yet.